# How to create a ranking algorithm for a game

Tags: algorithm, ranking, ranking-functions

I am creating a ranking formula for a game I am developing. I want to be able to find out who the best player is based on two criteria:

1. Time
2. Steps

There is a task *T* that each player has to complete. The idea is to complete it in *minimum time* and *minimum steps*.

I could not come up with anything without keeping a limited time (1800 seconds) and limited steps (25).

[image]

Based on the above calculation, player 5 is the best followed by player 1.

But we can clearly see that player 4 has better figures.

How can I improve this or is there any other way of calculating?

Comment: I don't understand why you divide *Difference in Time* by *Difference in steps*. Would it not make more sense to add them to each other instead?

Comment: yes..now I see it

Comment: There's no canonical way to arrange 2d data on a 1d scale. It's up to you to decide what makes sense depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use weighted arithmetic mean. Time and steps will have value. For example:

```
TimeV = 1
StepsV = 90

Score = (Time*TimeV+Steps*StepsV)/Time+Steps
```

You must decide which of this is more important time or number of steps. In example time and steps are important same.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the time and the steps.

Select a "max value" for time and a "max value" for steps (e.g. the 1800 and the 25 you use already). Now normalize this to 1. All time and step values should now be between 0 and 1. Finally add the normalized values together.

So for example 900/1800 = 0.5. And 12/25 = 0.48. If you add these together you'll get a score of 0.98. If you do this for each player, you'll find that they'll get the following scores:

- Player 1: 0.98
- Player 2: 0.82
- Player 3: 0.8267
- Player 4: 0.7733
- Player 5: 0.8667

From this you can see that player 4 has the lowest score, which is what you wanted.

If you want time or steps to weigh more than the other in the final score, you can change the max values for time and steps (which are now 1800 and 25) to adjust which is more important, or you can add weights before adding the two normalized values together.